# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foody/com.example.foody.StartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

In developing application using 'parse.com' to manage account, my application doesn't work (I developed by Android Studio). Please help me. I'm sorry for my poor English.
'StartActivity' is first Activity (I changed Manifest) and 'StartActivity' should change to 'LoginSignup.class' or  'MainActivity.class' but it doesn't. Oh my god

```
   package com.example.foody;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

/**
 * Created by 손승범 on 2015-07-28.
 */
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {

            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if(currentUser != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And logcat is this

```
07-29 16:02:21.517  23121-23121/com.example.foody E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.foody, PID: 23121
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foody/com.example.foody.StartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:304)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.getFromDisk(ParseObject.java:667)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1056)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1003)
            at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
            at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
            at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
            at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
            at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:1003)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.access$800(ParseUser.java:26)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:996)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:993)
            at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:61)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:993)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:979)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:966)
            at com.example.foody.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 27 in `StartActivity.java`?

Comment: It's
    if(ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot this

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Add this after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Ok. but i don;t think that should be causing NPE

Comment: Umm..my 'StartActivity.class' doesn't have layout. It just decide which activity is proper to exchange - LoginSignup or MainActivity that have layout and there exist setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) in LoginSignup and MainActivity class.

Comment: You are facing error in this line if(ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) { right?

Comment: Yes, null check missed for ParseUser.getCurrentUser(). That will solve his problem

Comment: @Seungbeom Can you post isLinked, getCurrentUser methods?

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check for `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`.
Change the if condition code from

```
if(ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
```

to

```
if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null && ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
```